# Not able to download PDF file using java api for azure

Tags: java, azure

How can I download pdf file from azure file storage. I know that there is a method `downloadText()` but it corrupts the pdf file. I have written code to download a uploaded file on azure and I have used `downloadText()` method but it's not working here.

However it downloads the pdf file but it says file corrupted or damaged.

Code sample which I am trying to do:

```
CloudFileDirectory sampleDir = rootDir.getDirectoryReference(path);
                        //Get a reference to the file you want to download
                        CloudFile file = sampleDir.getFileReference(fileStorageBean.getUniqueFileIdentifier());
                        //get file contents from azure file.
                        String fileContent = file.downloadText();
                        ESAPI.httpUtilities().setHeader(response, "Content-Disposition","attachment;");

                        response.setContentType(fileStorageBean.getMimeType());
                        response.setContentLength(file.getStreamWriteSizeInBytes());
                InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContent.getBytes());
```

Comment: Instead of downloading as text file, please try downloading to byte array directly or downloading to a stream. http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/file/CloudFile.html#downloadToByteArray(byte[], int). HTH.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav... yes that's where the problem was... downloadText().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `file.downloadToFile` method to download your `pdf` file from `Azure File Storage` to local.

***Sample Code:***

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.createCloudFileClient();

CloudFileShare share = fileClient.getShareReference("test");

CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.getRootDirectoryReference();

CloudFile file = rootDir.getFileReference("testFile.pdf");

File sourceFile = new File("E:\\AzureFile\\f.pdf");

file.downloadToFile(sourceFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Or you could use `file.download` method to download file to a stream.

```
OutputStream outs=response.getOutputStream();

file.download(outs);
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: @ShashiShekhar   It's great! You could mark my answer for others' reference on the Forum.Have a nice day!